# How to calculate if a given $N$ number is prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $N = 65537$, is $N$ prime ? Give a justification.

I have no idea how to do this, I think I have to use Fermat's little theorem, but I have no clue how to start using it $p|(a^p - a)$, $p$ - prime.

Can you guys give me a hint, or something ? Thank you.

Comment: a) trial division. Dividing by the primes $< 256$ isn't so much work [and actually, you only need to try $193$]. b) Proth's theorem.

Comment: $65537 = 2^{16}+1$, this is the Fermat number for $n=4$ as $F_n=2^{2^n}+1$. This is a prime number. The next Fermat number would be $F_5=2^{2^5}+1=4294967297$. Euler found that 641 is a factor of this number.

Comment: @MrYouMath yeah but with this formula $F_{n} = 2^{2^{n}} + 1$, you can only calculate $3,5,17...$ but what about $7,11,13$ ? How do I know that it will hit my $N$ prime ? what are the chances? Basically what I am saying is that your formula won't work for $N = 7$.

Comment: You asked if N=65537 is prime? @Daniel Fischer said a) trial division or b) Proth's theorem(from which it directly follows that $N=65537$ is prime). And i said that $N=65537=F_4$, which is known to be prime. If you need general methods for arbitrary numbers $N$ then follow the link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test#Fermat_primality_test

Comment: @MrYouMath well I thought that it is understandable that $N$ is arbitrary, so if I get another $N$ number, I need to use the same algorithm and test it.

Comment: @DanielFischer thanks, the first method seems quite fast for low $N$ numbers.

Comment: Yes, for small $N$, you can't beat a (clever) trial division. For larger $N$, things change. Still, unless you have special information about $N$, the first thing one does when testing primality is nevertheless trial division up to some sensible limit. Most numbers have at least one small prime factor, and those are quickly found by trial division. Only once you have established that your number has no small prime factors you start to use more elaborate tests.

Comment: @DanielFischer so in this case it would be sufficient as a proof to just do trial division ?

Answer (score 0):

Notice that from $2^{16}+1\equiv 0\pmod p$ you get $\text{ord}_p(2)=32$. Since the order divides $p-1$, you just have to test the primes of the form $p=32a+1$. Since you don't want them to be divisible by $3$, you have $a=3b+2$ or $a=3b$, that is $p=96b+65$ or $p=96b+1$. Combine this with $p<256$ and you don't have many cases to deal with ($b=0$ is silly, and $b\geq 3$ is already too much).

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but this formula won't work for every prime, for example $p=7$ it won't work for it. $2^2 + 1 = 5$ and $2^3 + 1=9$, so we passed $7$ which is prime.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand the question. Let me explain better: call $d$ be the order of $2$ mod $p$. Then $d$ divides $32$, so it is a power of $2$, but it does not divide $16$ because $2^{16}$ is not $1$ mod $p$. So $d$ is in fact $32$. For $p=7$, $2^{16}\equiv 2^4\equiv 5\pmod 7$ so it's not under consideration.

Answer (score 0):

The Fermat numbers are $F_n=2^{2^n}+1$, $n \ge 0$. The first few are

$$ 3, 5, 17, 257, 65537, \ldots $$

**Proposition.** Every prime divisor of $F_n$ is of the form $2^{n+2}k+1$.

Note that $F_n=(F_{n-1}-1)^2+1$. So test for primality of $F_n$, we need only to check for divisibility by all primes till $F_{n-1}-1$. Coupled with the Proposition, the search for possible prime divisors of $F_4$ is therefore narrowed to checking for divisors in the set

$$ \{2^6k+1: 2^6k+1\:\text{prime},2^6k+1 \le 256\} = \{193\}. $$

So $F_4$ must be prime if $193 \nmid F_4$.

If we apply this Proposition to $F_5$, the possible prime divisors of $F_5$ lie in the arithmetic progression $128k+1$. The first two primes in this progression which do not exceed $\sqrt{F_5}$ are $257$ and $641$. The latter divides $F_5$.

Here's a proof of the Proposition with some steps to be filled in by the interested reader.

*Proof of Proposition*. If $q \mid 2^{2^n}+1$, $q$ prime, then $2^{2^n} \equiv -1\pmod{q}$. Hence, $2^{2^{n+1}} \equiv 1\pmod{q}$, and we may deduce $\text{ord}_q\,2=2^{n+1}$. By Lagrange's theorem, $2^{n+1} \mid (q-1)$. So for $n>1$, $q \equiv 1\pmod{8}$. By Quadratic Reciprocity, $2$ is a quadratic residue modulo $q$. If $a^2 \equiv 2\pmod{q}$, then $\text{ord}_q\,a=2^{n+2}$. Again by Lagrange's theorem, $2^{n+2} \mid (q-1)$. $\blacksquare$